# "pin visual" missing in Power BI web application

Tags: powerbi

When I open a report in power BI web application, I'd like to pin visuals
to dashboard, but the `pin visual` functionality is missing.

Can I activate it somehow? In [this tutorial](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/excel-power-tools/sharing-power-bi-reports-qU0wk) there is a `pin visual` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-dashboard-pin-tile-from-report to learn how to pin a tile to dashboard. You have to mouse-over the upper right corner of the visual to "activate" this feature.

Note that you can't pin tiles from reports that are shared with you. And for some special custom visual or slicer visual, it is not supported to pin to dashboard.

Comment: Thank you. I have a feeling that i had a mouse-over the visual, it showed me drill down functionalities and on the left should be "pin visual", but it was missing. I will try it on monday.

Comment: I noticed that the graph has "pin visual", but the pivot table and slicer has not.